# WordPress: is it a good idea to improve meta query performance by adding tax query?

Tags: mysql, wordpress, query-performance

I'm aware that using taxonomies over metadata is preferred when it comes to posts grouping. In simple words [this](https://wordpress.org/support/article/taxonomies/) and [this](https://wordpress.org/support/article/custom-fields/) are saying  "use meta for unique data and taxonomy for repeating data(the one which groups posts)".

But I'm wondering if it is possible to improve meta query performance by introducing a taxonomy that will represent different ranges of that meta?

Let's suppose I have a shop with post type Products. Each Product has Price meta. I have millions of rows in the database meta table.
What if I'll add a Price Range taxonomy which will be used on front-end filters? Price Range will be like "1-100$", "100-1000$", etc. User clicks on "100-1000$" + sort by Price. This way I'll query posts tagged by "100-1000$" and only after that will sort them by Price meta. Will it increase query performance?

And how could it be implemented in case the user is allowed to input "from" and "to" Price? It is probably a good idea to use the approach above and just to add taxonomy meta for Price Range? This will look like this:
- User selects "90-900$"
- Fetch all the Price Range terms which match that range. Ie. "1-100" and "100-1000"
- Query posts that are in  "1-100" and "100-1000" Price Range(terms) and set meta value Price as >90 and <900
Will it increase performance too? This approach requires 2 queries : get terms(filtered by term meta), get posts.

I have no chance to check that with a really huge database as all my projects are not so big. But I'm still interested if any of my approaches will work for big sites?

**Edited (1):** I'm attaching PHP and SQL

Query by meta only:

```
new WP_Query([
    'post_type' => 'my_product',
    'meta_query' => [
        [
            'key'     => 'price',
            'value'   => 90,
            'compare' => '>=',
            'type'    => 'NUMERIC'
        ],
        [
            'key'     => 'price',
            'value'   => 900,
            'compare' => '<=',
            'type'    => 'NUMERIC'
        ]
    ]
]);
```

```
EXPLAIN SELECT  SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts.ID
    FROM  wp_posts
    INNER JOIN  wp_postmeta  ON ( wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id )
    INNER JOIN  wp_postmeta AS mt1  ON ( wp_posts.ID = mt1.post_id )
    WHERE  1=1
      AND  ( ( wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'price'
                      AND  CAST(wp_postmeta.meta_value AS SIGNED) >= '90' )
              AND  ( mt1.meta_key = 'price'
                      AND  CAST(mt1.meta_value AS SIGNED) <= '900' ) 
           )
      AND  wp_posts.post_type = 'my_product'
      AND  (   wp_posts.post_status = 'publish'
           OR  wp_posts.post_status = 'acf-disabled'
           OR  wp_posts.post_author = 1 AND  wp_posts.post_status = 'private'
           )
    GROUP BY  wp_posts.ID
    ORDER BY  wp_posts.post_date DESC
    LIMIT  0, 10



1   SIMPLE  wp_postmeta ref     post_id,meta_key    meta_key    767 const   1   Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort    
1   SIMPLE  mt1         ref     post_id,meta_key    meta_key    767 const   1   Using where 
1   SIMPLE  wp_posts    eq_ref  PRIMARY,...         PRIMARY       8 loc.own-acf-plugin.wp_postmeta.post_id  1   Using where
```

Query by tax and meta:

```
new WP_Query([
    'post_type' => 'my_product',
    'meta_query' => [
        [
            'key'     => 'price',
            'value'   => 90,
            'compare' => '>=',
            'type'    => 'NUMERIC'
        ],
        [
            'key'     => 'price',
            'value'   => 900,
            'compare' => '<=',
            'type'    => 'NUMERIC'
        ]
    ],
    'tax_query' => [
        [
            'taxonomy' => 'category',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => [ '0-100', '100-1000' ]
        ]
    ]
])
```

```
EXPLAIN SELECT  SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts.ID
    FROM  wp_posts
    LEFT JOIN  wp_term_relationships  ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id)
    INNER JOIN  wp_postmeta  ON ( wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id )
    INNER JOIN  wp_postmeta AS mt1  ON ( wp_posts.ID = mt1.post_id )
    WHERE  1=1
      AND  ( wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN (1,2) )
      AND  ( ( wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'price'
                      AND  CAST(wp_postmeta.meta_value AS SIGNED) >= '90' )
              AND  ( mt1.meta_key = 'price'
                      AND  CAST(mt1.meta_value AS SIGNED) <= '900' ) 
           )
      AND  wp_posts.post_type = 'my_product'
      AND  (   wp_posts.post_status = 'publish'
           OR  wp_posts.post_status = 'acf-disabled'
           OR  wp_posts.post_author = 1 AND  wp_posts.post_status = 'private'
           )
    GROUP BY  wp_posts.ID
    ORDER BY  wp_posts.post_date DESC
    LIMIT  0, 10



1   SIMPLE  wp_term_relationships   index   PRIMARY,term_taxonomy_id    PRIMARY 16  
    NULL
    1   Using where; Using index; Using temporary; Using f...   
1   SIMPLE  wp_postmeta             ref     post_id,meta_key       
   meta_key 767 const   1   Using where 
1   SIMPLE  mt1                     ref     post_id,meta_key    meta_key    767 const   1   Using where 
1   SIMPLE  wp_posts                eq_ref  PRIMARY,type_status_date,post_author    PRIMARY 8   loc.own-acf-plugin.wp_term_relationships.object_id  1   Using where
```

Comment: See this for a generic way to speed up many of the "meta" queries:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#speeding_up_wp_postmeta

Comment: Thank you @RickJames, I'll take a closer look at it!
Have you tested this solution? How much query speed was increased?
Have you faced any issues with this solution or does it work smoothly?

Comment: Note that there are two choices -- some users comment that `id` is really needed, hence the second suggestion there.  Speed: There is too much variation to get a good reading.  I suspect it would be possible to make a benchmark showing more than 2x.  But some users don't use "meta", so no benefit for them.  Testing:  Only indirectly; I have never used WP.

Comment: A big thanks @RickJames!
And just want to tell to each who is reading these comments: the question still remains - will tax query speed up the query as well?

Comment: As for the "tax" question, can you provide two competing SQL statements to compare?

Comment: @RickJames, added

Comment: Please provide `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` for each.  I suspect there is a substantive difference between them.

Comment: I've added `EXPLAIN` statement. Please note, that my DB is not a real-projcet DB and it has no Price meta and Price Range taxonomy. @RickJames

Comment: How many rows in each table?  Sounds like only 1, thereby making the `EXPLAIN` useless.

Comment: @RickJames, unfortunately this project is not real as I have mentioned. It is just a WP database in its initial state. I have no a big database to test my query with. That's why I was looking for help on Stack Overflow :(

Lets suppose database has 300.000 posts and tax query will reduce the match to 50.000 posts. Will this assumption work?

Answer (score 0):

The following issues are causing poor performance.  (I don't know which of these can be improved in WP.)

- `OR` is hard to optimize
- Two `JOINs` to `wp_postmeta`.  Can that be fixed by making it `JOIN` only once and do a `BETWEEN..AND..`?
- Adding an extra `JOIN` (to a taxonomy) *probably* slows it down.
- EAV schema pattern sucks anyway.
- WP's EAV schema has inefficient indexes.  See http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#speeding_up_wp_postmeta
- `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` costs something.  In particular, it can't quit after finding the desired 10 (the `LIMIT`).
- The `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY` are different, thereby necessitating an extra sort.  Changing both to `ID` would fix this.

Even if your one addition helps, it won't be enough to counteract the other 6 problems.

Perhaps the biggest fix would be to have a *numeric* column called `price` (and suitably indexed) in `wp_posts`.  But that is quite alien to the WP schema philosophy.

Comment: Thank you! I should learn all of these things! The thing I can say right now is: some of these statements are added by WP and some by its ACF plugin. I definitely should take a look at all of these and to find a way how to optimize it in the future!
And could WP_Query be optimized by extra tax query as I suggested? As you said it will not be an alien for WP thus will definitely be bugless.
@RickJames